# Getting an error when I do sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: drivers, 15.10

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid linux-signed-image-generic-lts-vivid python-ntdb thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgbm1 xorg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms (6.30.223.64somerville1) ...
Removing old oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-6.30.223.64somerville1 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.64somerville1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-6.30.223.64somerville1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-49-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.19.0-49-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-49-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: 15.04 is past End of Life, are you sure you are still on 15.04?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu! It would be helpful if you added a little more description about your setup and what you did to achieve this program output. Even if your problem was resolved now it would help future readers with the same problem to identify it. I'll give you an up-vote if you ping me after you [edit] your question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some old kernel(s) from a previous Ubuntu release installed that cause(s) compatibility issues when DKMS tries to compile kernel modules for it. You should delete them.

Start with

```
sudo apt-get purge -f 'linux-*-3.19*'
```

and/or see [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](/q/2793/175814).

Apt may refuse to delete these packages because of unconfigured packages (because a kernel module couldn't be compiled for them). In that case please update your question with what you tried to do and any error messages encountered in the process and ping me in the comment section of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a previous build crashed, I would remove the crash file (see path in the line below) and try another upgrade.

> [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187-dkms.0.crash'

If the build still crash, I would consult `/var/lib/dkms/oem-wireless-dw1550-1160187/6.30.223.64somerville1/build/make.log` to have more details.

Comment: The crash file wouldn't matter if the build didn't crash…